# Unreliable code coverage with quarkus-jacoco extension

Tags: code-coverage, quarkus, jacoco

We are using the `quarkus-jacoco` extension (version 2.4.2) in order to collect code coverage during tests. The problem we are facing is that it works unreliable. Most of the times, the coverage is recorded correctly but sometimes there is 0% coverage and the jacoco.xml files are not created at all. They are simply missing. No warning and errors are printed. If you run the very same process again coverage collection works perfectly.
Did anyone experience a similar issue? Is there any debugging we can turn on in order to track down the problem? Unfortunately the Maven output does not show any indication about Jacoco operations at all.

Comment: I am seeing this random problem happening on our code somtimes. Its realy random tho.